# Accessing hidden SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Currently I have a few lists in my SharePoint site that has been hidden from the user (via the hidden property which was set programmatically).  I was wondering whether there are any special urls/web or ways to access those lists?  e.g. {site}/lists/hiddenList or something similar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The URL for a Hidden list is no different than any other list, no hoops to jump through. You just need to know the base URL.

If it is not a Document Library, it will be located at `{siteurl}/Lists/{listname}/AllItems.aspx`. If it is a Document Library, it will be located at `{siteurl}/{listname}/Forms/AllItems.aspx`. These would give you the default list view assuming it is still called AllItems.aspx.

Comment: that aside, are there any other ways to access the hidden lists?  Its a bit like, if the programmer has forgotten the name of the lists that was hidden, are there any other ways to find out other than looking at the code? Thanks.

Comment: @BeraCim Part of the whole point of a hidden list is to avoid being listed with other lists. So through the out-of-box UI, there is no listing that will include those hidden things (just try finding the "Workflow History" list). For this kind of task, I would write a custom application page that enumerates the site's lists and just outputs their names and GUIDs, probably with links. I did one myself, but I also use [this CodePlex project](http://listfieldmanager.codeplex.com/). It, too, will list hidden lists and their GUIDs. Either way, it'll save the trouble of repeated code examination.

Answer (score 0):

Open the site collection in the free SharePoint designer. This allows you to browse through most of the content stored in SharePoint.